# How do you do a union of two tables in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I need to do a union of two tables using NHibernate and HQL.  I have found very little help online, and I want to know if it is possible and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer:

http://www.hibernate.org/117.html#A21

It doesn't currently support union or intersect.

Comment: Updated link: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#jive_content_id_Does_HQL_support_UNION_or_INTERSECT

Answer (score 1):

You could use a named sql-query and do the union in raw SQL.  NHibernate will be able to populate entity instances from the sql-query and return those as the query result.  See [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-creating) and [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-namedqueries).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe HQL supports unions, but you can write your own record transformer and author the sql by hand.