# NHibernate QueryOver - Join without path (or with "reversed" path)

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-criteria

I am trying to fetch several entities without having a single root entity ( the directed graph of entity-relations is only a **weakly connected graph**, not strongly connected) and I cant figure out how to do it in Nhibernates QueryOver api (or Linq, but that seems to be even weaker)

These are the relations I have:

`ClientTaxEntity` references 1 `Client` and N `Manufacturers`

`InstructionTemplate` references 1 `Client` and 1 `Manufacturer`

I want to get a result with all possible Client-Manufacturer pairs (possible = they are together within a ClientTaxEntity) and fetch a Template to them if it exists (null otherwise)

This is what I have tried so far:

```
        Client client = null;
        Manufacturer manufacturer = null;
        InstructionTemplate template = null;
        ClientTaxEntity taxEntity = null;

        InstructionTemplateInfo info = null;

        var query =Session.QueryOver<ClientTaxEntity>(() => taxEntity)
                   .JoinAlias(x => x.Client, () => client)
                   .JoinAlias(x => x.Manufacturers, () => manufacturer)
                   .Left
                   .JoinQueryOver(() => template, () => template,() => template.Client == client && template.Manufacturer == manufacturer);
        var result = query
            .SelectList(builder => builder
                        .Select(() => client.Name).WithAlias(() => info.ClientName)
                        .Select(() => client.Id).WithAlias(() => info.ClientId)
                        .Select(() => manufacturer.Name).WithAlias(() => info.ManufacturerName)
                        .Select(() => manufacturer.Id).WithAlias(() => info.ManufacturerId)
                        .Select(() => template.Id).WithAlias(() => info.TemplateId)
                        .Select(() => template.Type).WithAlias(() => info.Type)
            )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<InstructionTemplateInfo>())
            .List<InstructionTemplateInfo>();
```

The info object is the result I would like.

However the syntax `.JoinQueryOver(() => template` does not seem to be valid for a path parameter (exception says : `could not resolve property: template of: ClientTaxEntity`

Comment: I know I could do it in two queries since I have two root entities, but I am looking for a single DB query solution.

Comment: Is there a relationship betweeen `ClientTaxEntity` and `InstructionTemplate`?

Comment: No, there is not. I also tried it to replace the join with a subselect, but it fails if the result of sub-select yields more then 1 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you want when writing a query in SQL it would be necessary to write something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Client_Id, Client_Name, Manufacturer_Id, Manufacturer_Name
FROM
(
  SELECT Client.Id as Client_Id, Client.Name as Client_Name, 
         Manufacturer.Id as Manufacturer_Id, Manufacturer.Name as Manufacturer_Name
  FROM ClientTax
  INNER JOIN Client on Client.Id = ClientTax.Client_Id
  INNER JOIN Manufacturer on Manufacturer.Id = Manufacturer.Manufacturer_id

  UNION

  SELECT Client.Id, Client.Name, Manufacturer.Id, Manufacturer.Name
  FROM InstructionTemplate
  INNER JOIN Client on Client.Id = InstructionTemplate.Client_Id
  INNER JOIN Manufacturer on Manufacturer.Id = InstructionTemplate.Manufacturer_id
) a
GROUP BY Client_Id, Client_Name, Manufacturer_Id, Manufacturer_Name;
```

Unfortunately converting such a query to one of NHibernate's query APIs is not possible because NHibernate does not support the UNION statement*. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642873/does-nhibernate-hql-support-the-union-all-keyword) and the feature request [NH-2710](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2710) in NHibernate's bug tracker.

*Except when using `union-subclass`. See the [docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-unionsubclass) for further details

The only options I can see are

1. Perform an SQL Query and map this to a DTO

   ```
   public class InstructionTemplateInfo
   {
     public int Client_Id { get; set; }
     public string Client_Name { get; set; }
     public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
     public string Manufacturer_Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   then

   ```
   var result = session
          .CreateSQLQuery(theSQLQueryString)
          .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<InstructionTemplateInfo>())
          .List<InstructionTemplateInfo>();
   ```
2. Create a view in the database and map this like a normal entity.
3. If the DBMS supports multiple results sets, like SQL Server, you could write two queries but mark them both as `Future` and then merge the two results set in code, i.e.

   ```
   var resultSet1 = Session.QueryOver<ClientTaxEntity>(() => taxEntity)
              .JoinAlias(x => x.Client, () => client)
              .JoinAlias(x => x.Manufacturers, () => manufacturer)
              .SelectList(builder => builder
                .SelectGroup((() => client.Name).WithAlias(() => info.ClientName)
                .SelectGroup((() => client.Id).WithAlias(() => info.ClientId)
                .SelectGroup((() => manufacturer.Name).WithAlias(() => info.ManufacturerName)
                .SelectGroup((() => manufacturer.Id).WithAlias(() => info.ManufacturerId)
             .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<InstructionTemplateInfo>())
             .Future<InstructionTemplateInfo>;

   var resultSet2 = Session.QueryOver<InstructionTemplate>(() => taxEntity)
              .JoinAlias(x => x.Client, () => client)
              .JoinAlias(x => x.Manufacturers, () => manufacturer)
              .SelectList(builder => builder
                .SelectGroup((() => client.Name).WithAlias(() => info.ClientName)
                .SelectGroup((() => client.Id).WithAlias(() => info.ClientId)
                .SelectGroup((() => manufacturer.Name).WithAlias(() => info.ManufacturerName)
                .SelectGroup((() => manufacturer.Id).WithAlias(() => info.ManufacturerId)
             .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<InstructionTemplateInfo>())
             .Future<InstructionTemplateInfo>;

   var result = resultSet1.Concat(resultSet2 )
        .GroupBy(x=>x.ClientId+"|"+x.ManufacturerId)
        .Select(x=>x.First());
   ```

   The advantage of this approach is that the DBMS will only be hit once.
   See [Ayende's blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures) for further details about this feature.

Comment: I went with the Future approach, its exactly what I needed. thank you

Comment: Its a shame that NHibernate doesn't support unions but it looks like it would require a lot of changes to make it work. Fortunately as NHibernate is so flexible there's pretty much always more than one way to address an issue.