# SQL Union to NHibernate Criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, nhibernate, sqlite, sybase

There's a way to convert this SQL statement to a NHibernate Criteria?

```
(select b1.FieldA as Name, b1.FieldA as FullName from Sale b1 where b1.FieldA like '%john%' or b1.FieldA like '%john%' order by b1.Id desc)
union 
(select b2.FieldC as Name, b2.FieldD as FullName from Sale b2 where b2.FieldC like '%john%' or b2.FieldD like '%john%' order by b2.Id desc)
union 
(select c.FieldE as Name, c.FieldF as FullName from Client c where c.FieldE like '%john%' or c.FieldF like '%john%' order by c.Id desc)
```

I've found that NHibernate doesn't support Unions.

Comment: You can see the answear here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591200/union-with-nhibernate-and-criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've found two solutions. I perform each query separately than I concat the results. It's like a Union, but isn't performed in the DB, it's performed in memory.

```
var b1 = Session.Query<Sale>()
            .Where(x => x.FiledA.Contains(filter) || x.FiledB.Contains(filter))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.FiledA, x.FiledB })
            .Select(x => new Foo { FullName = x.Key.FiledA, Name = x.Key.FiledB })
            .Take(30)
            .ToList();

var b2 = Session.Query<Sale>()
            .Where(x => x.FiledC.Contains(filter) || x.FiledD.Contains(filter))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
            .GroupBy(x => new {x.FiledC, x.FiledD})
            .Select(x => new Foo {FullName = x.Key.FiledC, Name = x.Key.FiledD})
            .Take(30)
            .ToList();


var c = Session.Query<Client>()
            .Where(x => x.FiledE.Contains(filter) || x.FiledF.Contains(filter))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.FiledE, x.FiledF })
            .Select(x => new Foo { FullName = x.Key.FiledE, Name = x.Key.FiledF })
            .Take(30)
            .ToList();

return b1.Concat(b2)
         .Concat(c)
         .ToList()
         .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.FullName })
         .Select(x => x.First())
         .Take(30);
```

OR

```
var b1 = Session.CreateCriteria<Sale>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("FiledA")), "Name")
        .Add(Projections.Property("FiledB"), "FullName"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("FiledA", filter),
        Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("FiledB", filter)))
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
    .SetMaxResults(30)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Foo>())
    .List<Foo>();

var b2 = Session.CreateCriteria<Sale>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("FiledC")), "Name")
        .Add(Projections.Property("FiledD"), "FullName"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("FiledC", filter),
        Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("FiledD", filter)))
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
    .SetMaxResults(30)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Foo>())
    .List<Foo>();

var c = Session.CreateCriteria<Client>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("FiledE")), "Name")
        .Add(Projections.Property("FieldF"), "FullName"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("FiledE", filter),
        Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("FieldF", filter)))
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
    .SetMaxResults(30)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Foo>())
    .List<Foo>();

return b1.Concat(b2)
         .Concat(c)
         .ToList()
         .GroupBy(x => new {x.FullName, x.Name})
         .Select(x => x.First())
         .Take(30);
```

Comment: you're loading the objects in memory then union. Can you union before loading the objects in memory? in that case the SQL Query can remove any duplications or if you'd need to apply further Fetches that could work nicely.

Comment: Union is still not supported by NHibernate linq at the time of writing this. Taken the result set is small enough it should be fine to union in memory, otherwise I would rather use a named query.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a view.  It can be mapped directly in NHibernate and does not rely on a specific database implementation.  You should remove the where clauses, and then you can build your NHibernate criteria against "Name" and "FullName".

```
  (select b1.FieldA as Name, b1.FieldA as FullName from Sale b1 order by b1.Id desc)
  union 
  (select b2.FieldC as Name, b2.FieldD as FullName from Sale b2 order by b2.Id desc)
  union 
  (select c.FieldE as Name, c.FieldF as FullName from Client c order by c.Id desc)
```