# How to Union two Queries in LINQ to Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate, union, fluent

How to Union two Queries in LINQ to Fluent NHibernate?

They return the same type but the queries are over separate entities:

```
IQueryable<Event> eventQuery1 = session.Query<Event>().Where(e => e.EventType.Id == eventTypeId);

IQueryable<Event> eventQuery2 = session.Query<Nomination>().Select(n => n.Event).Distinct();
```

I tried the Union() and Concat() methods but they failed:

```
eventQuery1 = eventQuery1.Union(eventQuery2);

The UnionResultOperator result operator is not current supported
```

I don't want to load the objects from database then apply the concat, I'd like it to be done before the objects are returned from database so that I can apply some Fetches on the final list from the union.

Comment: Hope [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) example helps.

Comment: I said I tried the Union() and Contact() methods. they are not supported for NHibernate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Union to NHibernate Criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623146/sql-union-to-nhibernate-criteria)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that. I don't want to load all the objects and do the union in memory! I'd like to do the union against the SQL then load the objects (achieve better performance).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works with NHibernate LINQ, but a work-around is:

```cs
IQueryable<Event> eventQuery =
     session.Query<Event>()
            .Where(e => e.EventType.Id == eventTypeId
                     || session.Query<Nomination>()
                               .Select(n => n.Event.Id)
                               .Contains(e.Id))
```